# Why is it that in general relativity an object in spacetime takes the path of longest possible proper time?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time

Why is it that in general relativity an object in spacetime takes the path of longest possible proper time?
Please answer in simple words...

Comment: Why is momentum conserved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it that in general relativity an object in spacetime takes the path of longest possible proper time?

What you stated is not quite accurate. An object that experiences "weightlessness" takes the path of longest possible proper time. If there were no gravity, one could say that an object which is in "inertial motion" would take the path of longest possible proper time. However, because of gravity, we want to re-define "inertial motion" to mean the curved paths that an object with no force on it (other than gravity, if one is considering gravity a force) will take.

*Why* is it that way? At the moment, general relativity is the "base theory". We can explain other things in terms of general relativity, but we can't explain general relativity in terms of some underlying theory, because we don't have any underlying theory at the moment. The best we can say is that general relativity rests upon observable data and experiment, but not upon some other theory.

Comment: This also is not quite right. e.g. A body in a circular orbit in the Schwarzschild metric takes a certain proper time to get back to its starting point. If you throw it upwards it will also return to its starting point. Both of these are valid routes but take a different amount of proper time. As I understand it, the route taken is the one with the largest proper time chosen from possibilities that are very close. i.e. a local maximum but not a global maximum.

Comment: @ProfRob A fair point.

Comment: Does this mean that the question I asked above is actually an assumption or requirement for general relativity to work and we can't really question why objects in inertial motion will take longest possible time?

Comment: Yes, the question you ask is fundamental to GR. You can always _ask_ why, but in this case we don't have a "more basic theory" to explain why. Even though we don't have an answer at this point, science moves forward by people pondering questions like this, and coming up with models that can be tested. So it isn't a pointless question per se. But it may never be answered, we don't know.

Comment: Makes more sense now thanks!